# What's the difference between GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

RubyGems is a package manager for the Ruby programming language that provides a standard format for distributing Ruby programs and libraries (in a self-contained format called a "gem"), a tool designed to easily manage the installation of gems, and a server for distributing them. It is analogous to EasyInstall for the Python programming language. RubyGems is now part of the standard library from Ruby version 1.9.

That said, what's the difference between GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

`GEM_PATH` provides the locations (there may be several) where gems can be found.

`GEM_HOME` is where gems will be installed (by default).

(Therefore `GEM_PATH` should include `GEM_HOME`).

Comment: It's not particularly clear from your answer. `GEM_PATH` is like `PATH` for gems (a list of directories where gems are located). At least `chruby` sets `GEM_HOME` as the first item in `GEM_PATH`.

Comment: How do you delimit multiple paths? Is it the same as PATH, using a colon character? `:`

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Answer (score 15):

Also interesting notice. At least on Wndows XP, don't know about other platforms.

Set `GEM_HOME` in Windows:

```
C:\>set GEM_HOME=C:\sbox\ruby\dump\.gems
```

Now let's check this.

1) In Windows ENVs. All OK, as expected:

```
C:\>set
...
GEM_HOME=C:\sbox\ruby\dump\.gems
...
```

2) With `gem env`. Notice it puts `GEM_HOME` along with `GEM_PATH`s but at the first place:

```
C:\>gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-02-24 patchlevel 0) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/sbox/ruby/dump/.gems
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby200/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/sbox/ruby/dump/.gems/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/sbox/ruby/dump/.gems
     - C:/Documents and Settings/User/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
     - C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

3) Now with `bundle env`:

```
C:\>bundle env
Bundler 1.3.4
Ruby 2.0.0 (2013-02-24 patchlevel 0) [i386-mingw32]
Rubygems 2.0.3
GEM_HOME C:\sbox\ruby\dump\.gems
GEM_PATH
```

`GEM_PATH` is empty, it means default value. But from where does it take the default value? See `gem env`.