# Can't install or update gems: YAML parse error

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am trying to install Compass and Jekyll, but the gem commands fail:

```
$ gem update
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:154:in `parse': (<unknown>): couldn't parse YAML at line 2 column 0 (Psych::SyntaxError)
```

From googling, I see that Ruby has updated it's YAML parser and that gems need to update their `config/boot.rb` file, but that doesn't help me unless I fork every gem that I  install.

Here is my .gemrc, it is the only place where I could have screwed something up:

```
gemhome: /home/dan/.gems
gempath:
    - /home/dan/.gems
```

Ruby version: `ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]`, installed using apt-get on Ubuntu.

What do I have to do to start installing ruby gems? I know almost nothing about ruby, I just want to install some software that is distributed as gems.

**update**

Looking at my question, I see that the ruby version in the error message and `ruby --version` are different. How do the ruby command and the gem command decide which version to use? Does it matter that they are different? **update**: I now have only ruby 1.9.3. The problem must be with my `.gemrc`

**update**

Removing my .gemrc and installing as root works. What is wrong with my .gemrc?

Comment: Any particular reason why you use ruby-1.8.7? It was retired last June. Maybe try a newer Ruby installed e.g. with RVM or chruby.

Comment: It must have been previously installed using apt-get. I will uninstall it now that I have installed the ruby1.9.1 package.

Comment: update re: Yes, it does matter. You can see the paths used with `gem env`, however, it's usually the Linux distro which deals with switching between different Ruby versions installed at the same time. I'm all Gentoo, so can't help you there, but you might want to look for binaries like `ruby18`, `gem18`, `ruby19` and `gem19`. Probably your `ruby` and `gem` binaries are only symlinks.

Comment: I uninstalled the ruby package, so now ruby1.9.1 is the only ruby package installed. However, `ruby --version` is `ruby 1.9.3p0`. Maybe I should find a PPA to install ruby 1.9.3 from. The symlinks route to ruby seems convoluted: '/usr/bin/ruby -> /etc/alternatives/ruby -> /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1`. I'm going to uninstall all rubies and get 1.9.3 from a PPA.

Comment: I installed 1.9.3, which has symlinks for 1.9.1, and I still get the same error that I started with. Installing gems as root no longer works. Maybe I should downgrade to the version that uses the old YAML parser.

Comment: I removed `.gemrc` again, and that gets me around the problem. `.gemrc` is yaml, maybe there is a syntax error there?

Answer (score 1):

The Yaml syntax is valid. (See http://yamllint.com/).

However, the problem lies in the variables names `gemhome` and `gempath` - they are supposed to be `GEM_PATH` and `GEM_HOME`.

See [What's the difference between GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277227/whats-the-difference-between-gem-home-and-gem-path) for more info.

You could type in `gem env` before and after removing the .gemrc file and you should see a difference in the gem path.

The gem configuration file is not really need in your case since your GEM_PATH/ GEM_HOME don't need to be changed from the defaults...

Comment: Using `GEM_HOME` and `GEM_PATH` didn't change the gem installation directory, but the two variables do show up in `gem env`. I see that `/home/dan/.gem` is one of the default gem home paths, so you're right, I shouldn't need a `.gemrc` at all. I am trying to get gems to install under my home directory so that I don't have to be root to manage them, but that's a subject for another question. Is `GEM_HOME` not the right way to change the gem install path?

Comment: `gem install <gem> --user-install` does what I want. No need for a `.gemrc`.

Answer (score 0):

To install gems below your home directory, use the `--user-install` parameter:

```
gem install <gem> --user-install
```

Mentioned in the [ruby gem FAQ](http://guides.rubygems.org/faqs/). A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643629/how-to-install-gems-without-sudo) suggest using [RVM](http://rvm.io/) to manage gems. It installs gems below the home dir.