# rubygem is installed but now in LOCAL GEMs database

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rhel7

I have a RedHat 7 system and I have installed the ruby 2.0.0.648 and rubygem 2.0.14 package and it has also installed a few dependent gems.

My problem is when I run the
`gem list` command I don't see any of the gems.

If I cd into the /usr/share/gems/gems/ directory I can see all of the files.

My question is…

How can I force the “gems command” to scan the /usr/share/gems/gems directory and update the
*** LOCAL GEMS *** database?

There has to be a way to manually edit the files to tell the gems command that all of the files are really on the system.

Comment: Install RVM with `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`; install Ruby with `rvm install 2.0.0`. [Don't](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/psa-do-not-use-system-ruby) [use](https://chrisherring.co/posts/why-you-shouldn-t-use-the-system-ruby) [system Ruby](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2014/05/15/never-use-system-ruby-ever/). (and if possible, please use a newer version of Ruby as support for 2.0 [ended three years ago](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2016/02/24/support-plan-of-ruby-2-0-0-and-2-1/))

Comment: This system cannot be added to the internet. (it totally closed off)

I'm not an rvm expert but I think that tool works by automatically downloading gems from the network, right?   If so then that tool would not work since I dont have any internet access, 

ls -tr /usr/share/gems/gems/
 shows all of the gems.

Is there a way to make them appear in the 

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

databse?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the path to your gems by running the following command in your shell (or by adding it to your shell profile and reloading your shell):

```
export GEM_PATH=/usr/share/gems/gems
```

After running this command you can verify that the change has taken effect by running `gem env`:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  <snipped>
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/share/gems/gems
  <snipped>
```

It sounds like you are not installing additional gems since your system is not connected to the Internet, but if you were to use the `gem install` command then you would also want to set `GEM_HOME` to the same path:

```
export GEM_HOME=/usr/share/gems/gems
```

`GEM_PATH` is where `gem` and `bundler` will find gems and `GEM_HOME` is where gems will be installed.

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11277228/3784008) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/203376/218427).