# gem locations in macOS with chruby and TextMate preferences

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, textmate, chruby

I having trouble getting Ruby gems to work right with TextMate (TM) and chruby on macOS.

Clean install of Mojave (now v10.14.4) on a 2017 iMac about six months ago.

Trying to use Ruby-2.6.2, although earlier versions have been installed. System Ruby is v2.3.7

I have ended up with gems in at least three locations:

`~/.rubies/ruby-2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/`
`~/.gem/ruby/2.6.2/gems/`
`/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/`

TextMate relies on its Preferences for gem and Ruby locations. As a start I have the following: 
 [image]
GEM_HOME is unset because I don't see why it's needed, although I've frequently read to set it as shown or similar. [GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277227/whats-the-difference-between-gem-home-and-gem-path) are defined as

GEM_PATH provides the locations (there may be several) where gems can be found.

GEM_HOME is where gems will be installed (by default).

The problem is that when I run this script (after the error not included) in TM

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
system ('gem env') # for debugging
puts "\nGem.path: #{Gem.path}"
puts "\ngem list:"
system ('gem list') # for debugging 
require 'fileutils'
include FileUtils
require 'find'
require 'yaml'
require "time"
require 'irb'
require 'mini_exiftool'
```

The result is:

```
Running “PhotoName-GPScoord.rb”…
ruby 2.6.2p47 (2019-03-13 revision 67232) [x86_64-darwin18]
Theme:  
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.7 (2018-03-28 patchlevel 456) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/gscar/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/gscar/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Site
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-18
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0
     - /Users/gscar
     - /.rubies/ruby-2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
     - /.gem/ruby/2.6.2/gems/
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-document"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Users/gscar/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/Bundle Support.tmbundle/Support/shared/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/texbin
     - /opt/local/bin

Gem.path: ["/Users/gscar", "/.rubies/ruby-2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0", "/.gem/ruby/2.6.2/gems/", "/Users/gscar/.rubies/ruby-2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0"]

gem list:
<about 100 gems>
mimemagic (0.3.3)
mini_exiftool (2.9.0)
mini_magick (4.6.1)
<about 20 gems>

LoadError: cannot load such file — mini_exiftool

method require  in kernel_require.rb at line 54
method require  in kernel_require.rb at line 54
method <main>   in PhotoName-GPScoord.rb at line 19
  copy output
```

TextMate puts this in the top right of the output [image]

Line 19 is `require 'mini_exiftool'`

`mini_exiftool` is in the gem list, but why the error?

If I run the script using the system Ruby (taking defaults, nothing set in TM)
[image: System Ruby]

The script runs with the following output:

```
Running “PhotoName-GPScoord.rb”…
ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]
Theme:  
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.7 (2018-03-28 patchlevel 456) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/gscar/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/gscar/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Site
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-18
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0
     - /Users/gscar/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-document"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Users/gscar/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/Bundle Support.tmbundle/Support/shared/bin

Gem.path: ["/Users/gscar/.gem/ruby/2.3.0", "/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0", "/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0"]

gem list:

<long list of gems including mini_exiftool (2.9.0)>
```

This particular script is OK with 2.3.7, but others may not be.

Thanks for any help.

This posting is a simplification of an [earlier posting from me](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53202164/edit). I think I've boiled the problem down.

Comment: I suspect that there is a mismatch between your Ruby and RubyGems. In second line it says `2.6.2p47` but I see Ruby 2.3.7 in `gem env`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Ruby 2.3.7 is the macOS system Ruby, but I think the script in the top example is running in 2.6.2. TextMate puts up this in the window (Apparently can't add an image here, I'll update the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed `GEM_HOME` and `GEM_PATH` to `$HOME/.gem/ruby/2.6.2:$HOME/.rubies/ruby-2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0` based on copying the those variables from what showing up when running from the terminal. Lu's comment made me look a little harder at what was being reported. Basically I was missing `$HOME/` in the second path (after the colon). I have been fiddling with this for months

Comment: Glad that you found the solution. Nitpick: `$GEM_HOME` is supposed to contain only one path, while `$GEM_PATH` can hold multiple (similar to `$PATH`).

Comment: Point taken. I had read that, but most people use the same for both. I've changed now to `GEM_HOME` to `$HOME/.gem/ruby/2.6.2`. I barely understand this and `$PATH` and in fact I don't have `PATH` set in TextMate (even though I've read many places what to set these to).